# RStudio/Quarto: YAML definitions in qmd-document called with rmarkdown::render are ignored

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I am looping through a set of parameters with which I generate multiple reports by using `rmarkdown::render(input = "report_template.qmd")` but the definitions in the the YAML-header in the called input document are ignored.

My document `report_template.qmd` has the following YAML-header:

```
title: |
  ![](images/image.png)  <br>
  <span style="color:black">Line1</span><br>
  <span style="color:black">`r params$param1`</span><br>
  <span style="color:black">`r params$param2`</span>
author: "Me"
date: |
  `r Sys.Date()`
format:
  html:
    theme: minty
    embed-resources: true
    df-print: paged
execute: 
 message: false
 echo: false
params:
  param1:
    label: "label1"
    value: "value1"
  param2:
    label: "label2"
    value: "value2"
```

When I render the report directly with "Render" from the document tab in RStudio it works perfectly.

When I render the report multiple times for different values of param1 and param2 from another qmd-document it still works but all the yaml definitions above (except title, author, date) are ignored.
I lose the html-formating and the execution-settings for the code chunks (I like to hide the code with `echo: false`).

Here is the chunk I use:

```
#| eval: false
#| echo: true

render_report <- function(param1, param2) {
  rmarkdown::render(
    "report_template.qmd", 
    output_dir = "reports",
    params = list(
      param1 = param1,
      param2 = param2
    ),
    output_file = paste0("reports/", 
                         gsub(x = paste0("report_", 
                                  param1, 
                                  "_", 
                                  param2, 
                                  ".html"), 
                       pattern="[ /]", 
                       replacement = "_")
    )
  )
}

# looping through all parameters
for (row in 1:nrow(parameter_df)) {
  param1 <- parameter_df$parameter1[row]
  param2 <- parameter_df$parameter2[row]
  render_report(param1, param2)
}
```

**Do I have to specify somewhere that I want the yaml definitions included?**